# How to get my contact card/id on Android?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

How do I get my contact card/id of a Android phone? eg: the owner of the phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by the Android platform. 
On some phones (HTC, Sony Ericsson) there is a provider (e.g HTC uses content://contacts/myContactCard) that will retreive this, but this is not supported on all devices.

Comment: Where do I lookup such documentation eg: HTC's?

Comment: It is undocumented. A rooted phone and smali (http://code.google.com/p/smali/) is the only way. If you query the above provider on an HTC phone you can iterate over the fields to give you the contact structure.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported but there is a ticket on android.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3898

Please star it in order to this ticket get a higher priority.

Comment: The issue you linked to is not the same issue the OP has.  
 The issue you linked to is that the local profile and Google profile of the user aren't synced. The issue of the OP is that he needs an easy way to grab the user's profile info.

Comment: @Dennis the problem is that android has not a user profile info and this is what that ticket is about

Comment: Not from what I understood. The user profile info is stored in the "ME" contact card on newer Android devices. The problem in the ticket you linked to is, as described by the person who opened the ticket, "My Contact Card on my phone is not synced to my Google profile". I voted up your answer regardless, because I do think that ticket deserves more attention.